# Loop is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

I have create a javascript to change the audio after the audio ended.

```
var songlist = new Array("a.mp3", "b.mp3", "c.mp3", "d.mp3", "e.mp3", "f.mp3");
var dir = "music/";
var curr_track = 0;
var isfirstrun;

function start()
{
    if(curr_track == songlist.length)
        curr_track = 0;
    var track = document.getElementById('track');
    track.innerHTML = curr_track;
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
    isfirstrun = true;
    audio.src = dir+songlist[curr_track];
    audio.load();
    audio.play();
    if(isfirstrun == true)
    {
        audio.addEventListener('ended', function(){ curr_track++; start();}, false); 
        isfirstrun = false;
    }
}
```

And inside the HTML,

```
<body onload="start();">
```

The `track` used in the code is to show what is the current track number, and I found out that the output is

```
0    then    1    then     3     then    7
```

Hence, it is missing `c.mp3`, `e.mp3` and `f.mp3` from the `songlist`.

How can I solve the problem of the looping?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every time the song ends, you are adding another event handler. This is why you see +1, +2, +4 etc. because the number of event handlers doubles each time around.

This is the main reason why I prefer to use `audio.onended = function() {curr_track++; start();};`

But anyway, to fix this all you have to do is have an "isfirstrun" variable, starting at `true`, then only add the event listener if it is true and set it to false.

Comment: About the `onended`, it's not working on my Chrome browser, and I tried also `ended`.

Comment: sorry for my weak programming that I cannot fix the code as mentioned to have an `isfirstrun` variable. I'm still get the same output. I edited the my post. Can I have an example?

Comment: I found out that I forget the conditions for `isfirstrun` is false. Thanks Kolink.

Comment: You are repeating yourself. Only the `addEventListener` should be in the `if` block.